# Writing NPM package, how do I specify that a PNG file path is in reference to the node_module script as opposed to from where it's imported

Tags: node.js, npm, import, path

I'm writing a npm package that requires importing PNG files from within the package:

Directory Structure

```
__test__
      __test__/test.js
src
      src/resources
             src/resources/PNG Image File
      src/index.js
```

I'm using `require(../src/index.js)` from within `test.js`.

Whenever I try to reach `./resources/image.png` from `index.js`, the path is attempted from within `__test__` (because it's technically being imported an run by `test.js`.

I can't use the path `../src/resources` because the goal is to create this as an NPM package that can be imported from anywhere.

What's the best way to specify within `index.js` that no matter where it's run, it should be looking within it's own directory for these image files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__dirname` to represent the directory where your module was loaded from which is independent of how it was loaded.

So, from within `index.js`, you can refer to your PNG file llocation ike this:

```
let pngFileDirectory = path.join(__dirname, "..", resources);
```

And, if you know the filename you're looking for:

```
let pngFile = path.join(__dirname, "..", resources, "myFile.png");
```

Done this way, you dynamically construct the path relative to your own module file.  Since the image file is part of the same NPM installation, the PNG file is in a fixed relative location to your own module file and this is independent of how your module was loaded or what the current working directory is in the project.  Using `__dirname` is the key.